# How to determine if the subgroup $H$ of order $p^2$ has an element of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

This question is in service of answering the problem:

> Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_{13} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_9$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{13} \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3)$

Where $G$ is a group of order $2925 = 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 13$ and $N$ has been shown (in a previous part of this problem) to be a subgroup of order $25$ and, more specifically, a Sylow $5$-subgroup and furthermore a normal subgroup since $n_5(G/N) = 1$

---

Now for this problem I have shown up to this point that $$G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}_{13} \rtimes H$$

To determine the subgroup structure of $H$ I am to use the result of an exercise in the book that states that:

> Let $p \geq 2$ be a prime and prove that any group, $G$, of order $p^2$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. Hint: If there exists an element of order $p^2$ then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$

So first, I'm assuming it's the case that if there does not exists an element of order $P^2$ then we have $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. Correct?

Next, how exactly do I go about figuring out if there exists such an element? I know that Cauchy's Theorem tells us that if there's a prime $p$ which divides the order of a group then there's an element $g \in G$ with $\lvert g \rvert = p$. However if $p^2$ divides the group then it's not necessarily the case that there exists an $h \in G$ such that $\lvert h \rvert = p^2$

Comment: Why in the world are you using $\Xi$ as notation for a group? That is very, very strange in the context of everything else you wrote.  Use $H$.

Comment: Yup. Impressive to see someone use capital $\Xi$, but I stopped reading the question once I saw there was no particular reason for using such an inconvenient variable. OP, I assure you you'll get more and better attention for your question if you use H.

Comment: How do you figure out if there is such an element? Consider the $p$th power of each element. If you always get the identity, then there is no element of order $p$. If you do not always get the identity, then there is. It's Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: I never realized there would be so much hostility to my choice of notation. Just felt like doing something different, on a whim. My apologies. I will change it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, wouldn't getting the identity from the $p^{\text{th}}$ power of an element mean that the element has order $p$ though? So, in that case every element would have order $p$? It was my understanding that the order of an element, $g$, was the integer $n$ such that $g^n = e$

Comment: If $x^n=e$, then $x$ has order *dividing* $n$. If $x^p=e$ then $x$ has order dividing $p$, hence either order $p$ or order $1$. The order of $g$ is the **least** positive $k$ such that $g^k=e$. Since the order of an element divides the order of the group (Lagrange's Theorem), in a group of order $p^2$ every element has order either $1$, $p$, or $p^2$. If every element has order dividing $p$, then no element has order $p^2$. If some element has order $p^2$, then not every element has order dividing $p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. Thank you for clearing that up for me. I guess I'm struggling to see how I can tell if there exists an element of order $p^2$ or, to tell if every element has order dividing $p$ for this specific group. What we know about the group is that it's a Sylow $3$-subgroup so as a $3$-group the order of $H$ is a power of $3$ but that's obvious, also the center of the group contains more elements than just the identity (though I'm not sure how relevant that is), all elements must divide $9$ so as you say all elements have order $1,3$ or $9$. I just don't see how to rule out orders

Comment: I mean, we must have an element of order $1$ since every group has an identity element in it, by definition. We must have at least an element of order $3$ by Cauchy's Theorem. I just am not sure how to prove or disprove the existence of an element of order $9$.

Comment: What do you mean "this specific group"? There **is no specific group**. You are being asked to show that there are only two possibilities **in general**. So *either* you have that your group of order $9$ has elements of order $9$, in which case it's cyclic of order $9$; or else it doesn't have elements of order $9$, in which case, being abelian, it must be isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$. Those are the only two possibilities, and you must explore them both.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies, for "this specific group" I was just referring to the finite group of order $9$, but as you point out it can be isomorphic to one of $2$ groups. I think what I'm getting hung up on is that the wording of the problem seems to indicate we are meant to discover the exact structure of the group, i.e., show that the group has elements of order $9$ and hence $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_9$, or else $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Hence my asking how exactly to show the existence of such an element.

Comment: Again, there is no specific group, so you cannot discover anything specific about it. The problem asks you to establish that you will have one of two possibilities. Which possibility occurs for any particular group will depend on whether certain conditions are present or not present. But since you do not in fact have a specific group, what you have to show is that no matter what happens, you **must** fall into one of the two cases. Basically, "if $P$, then possibility 1; if not $P$, then possibility $2$". You are asking how to show that $P$ is happening. That's the wrong question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Thanks for sticking with me on this. I understand now. I suspected that might be the case but the specific wording of "You will use exercise 3.4.3 to determine the structure of the sylow $3$-subgroup of $G/N$" had me quite confused, and believing we required a specific answer despite what everything else about the problem was indicating. I, again, appreciate your confirmation I see now I was making this much more difficult than it needed to be.

Comment: That result tells you that either you have one structure for $G/N$, or else you have another structure. Each of those structures will lead you to one isomorphism type, and that result tells you those are the only two possible isomorphism types.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun, I'm not sure it's a publicly available book but it's Intro to Abstract Algebra by Leininger. It's a draft, compiled from lecture notes from the Spring '16 Algebra I course at University of Illinois Urbana-Champaign. It's the required text for an online course I'm taking at UIUC